# iCloud keychain problems - asking passwords, can't change password, can't unsync

Tags: icloud, password, keychain

Main symptom: When I reboot I get multiple prompts asking for the "local items" keychain password. 
Details:

- The password required is my old iCloud password, not my current user account password nor my current iCloud password
- The keychain access program lists "local items" as a keychain until I log in to one with my old password -- after which it changes to "iCloud"
- The option to reset the password for both local items (before entering the PW) and iCloud keychain (after) are both greyed out.
- I cannot stop syncing my iCloud keychain. When I uncheck the box, the box rechecks itself in a second or two.
- to confuse things, I used my iCloud account as my login for the computer briefly

I have looked at several topics to guide me, but none of them have led to a resolution as it seems the problem is always slightly different.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just commenting to say I have this same problem and haven't found a solution yet either.

Comment: This starts to happens to me after change admin password. I followed some instructions in Apple's support website but didn't work. The password for keychains remains the old one, that's why keep asking for it.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to bump an old thread, but I found this simple solution. At least in my experience, the password for the default keychain cannot be changed, so:

1) Create a new keychain (`File→New Keychain… ⌥⌘N`). I named it `temp` and gave it a simple password.

2) Right-click the `temp` keychain and select `Make Keychain “temp” Default`.

3) Select the original keychain.

4) `Edit→Change Password for Keychain [name]…` should now be accessible. Select it and change the password to your heart’s content.

5) Right-click the original keychain and select `Make Keychain [name] Default`.

6) Right-click the `temp` keychain and select `Delete Keychain “temp”`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you ever found the solution, or if Mark's solution worked for you. I recently ran into this issue, and followed the steps at https://scatterbin.blogspot.com/2018/08/change-password-for-keychain-local-items.html and it worked for me.

It seems to be a little known solution, and it took me a while to find this.

From the page:

> The following steps should allow you to change the Local Items
>   keychain password, provided that you know your old password.
>
> Restart your Mac. When prompted to enter the password for the "Local
>   Items" keychain, click on Cancel and do not enter your password. Note:
>   you may be prompted multiple time and need to click on Cancel multiple
>   times. Open up Keychain Access (you can look for it via Spotlight).
>   Lock the "login" keychain (yes, the "login" keychain). Unlock the
>   "login" keychain. After unlocking the "login" keychain, you should now
>   be prompted to change the password for the "Local Items" keychain.
>   Change the password to match your user account password.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, also tied to using my iCloud account to login.

I was able to resolve the issue by going to System Preferences > iCloud and deselecting 'Keychain' from the list. This reverted the "iCloud" keychain to "local items" in Keychain Access.

The next time the "unlock local items" pop-up appeared, I entered the password and got another pop-up asking me to change my password (enter old, enter new, re-enter new).

I changed the password there to match my login password, logged out and then back in again, and haven't received anymore notifications.

Comment: Like the original question, for me if I go to System Preference, iCloud and untick 'Keychain' a second later it ticks itself.